# Operator precedence in C, Celsius to Fahrenheit

Tags: c

I have this piece of code that turns a temperature in Celsius to Fahrenheit using various orders of expressions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double temf;
    double temc = 17.0;

    temf = (9 / 5) * temc + 32;
    printf("%g\n", temf);

    temf = 9 / 5 * temc + 32;
    printf("%g\n", temf);

    temf = 9 * temc / 5 + 32;
    printf("%g\n", temf);

    temf = 32 + 9 * temc / 5;
    printf("%g\n", temf);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And it returns

```
49
49
62.6
62.6
```

Can someone explain to me why

```
(9/5) * 17.0 + 32 = 17.0 + 32
```

What is the actual expression being executed when you type the first 2 calculations?

Comment: Expressions involving binary operators are evaluated left to right, subject to the operator precedence rules, so the first two expressions are evaluated as `temf = (((9 / 5) * temc) + 32)`. In the `(9 / 5)` subexpression, both operands are integers, so it uses integer division, discarding the fractional part.

Comment: In comparison, the third expression is evaluated as `temf = (((9 * temc) / 5) + 32`. The `(9 * temc)` subexpression involves an `int` and a `double`, so the `int` `9` is converted to `double` and the result is a `double`. The `((9 * temc) / 5)` subexpression therefore involves division of a `double` `(9 * temc)` by an `int` `5`, so the `int` `5` is converted to `double` and floating point division is used.

Answer (score 4):

`(9. / 5.) = 1.8` is double division and `(9/5) = 1` is int division.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double temf;
    double temc = 17.0;

    temf = (9. / 5.) * temc + 32.;
    printf("%g\n", temf);

    temf = 9. / 5. * temc + 32.;
    printf("%g\n", temf);

    temf = 9. * temc / 5. + 32.;
    printf("%g\n", temf);

    temf = 32. + 9. * temc / 5.;
    printf("%g\n", temf);
}
```

Results:

```
62.6
62.6
62.6
62.6
```

Answer (score 4):

In C, you should take care of the types of numerical constants, the constant itself will determine what type it will have. If you write a constant as `9` then it will be an integer, if you write `9.0` then it will be a double, if you write `9.0f`, then it will be a float.

So if you just type `9/5` then it will be an integer division and will obey the rules of integer division.  The result of the integer / operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded. `9/5 = 1.8`, if we discard the fractional part then it will be `1`. `1 * 17.0 = 17.0`.

To get to proper result you should write `9.0/5.0`, this will be a division of two double values and the result will be 1.8 as a double.